# Encoding HTML using Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC 2.0, I have an actionlink that is used for comments on a particular post:

```
Html.ActionLink("Comments", "Details", new { id = String.Format("{0}#comments",item.Title) })
```

What happens however is that the #comments gets encoded to %23comments, which doesn't work.  Any ideas on getting around that?  I've tried Url.Action (same issue) and would prefer not to hard code the link in an href.

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks,
-Simon

Comment: Why would you use a hash in the id? Is that even valid HTML?

Comment: You might want to look at `fragment`, if you're trying to put things after the actual url. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan - you were right, "fragment" is the right parameter here.  Simply set fragment to the name of the HTML div, and it will get correctly appended.

Thanks,
-Simon